# LWC Boolean Properties

Tags: lightning-web-components, boolean

I have encountered an error of
`LWC1503: Invalid public property initialization for "booleanVariableName". Boolean public properties should not be initialized to "true", consider initializing the property to "false".`

I think this error is related to this LWC developer guide, [Boolean Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_boolean).

In my case, boolean value is set dynamically in HTML such as:

```html
<!-- parent.html -->
<template>
    <c-bool show={booleanVariableName}></c-bool>
</template>
```

So, I thought I can toggle boolean value either `true` or `false` from JavaScript, so I could set `booleanVariableName` to `true`.

I don't understand why LWC has this limitation, does somebody please explain to me?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to add snippets of your actual code including the property declaration, how it is used and how the parent is trying to set it. Using samples from the documentation does not help if it is not identical to your usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_boolean) says

> Always set the default value for a boolean public property to false. If you set the default value to true instead in bool.js, there’s no way to statically toggle the value to false in markup.

in you question you specified you need to toggle between true and false dynamically, if it's possible, initialize the **booleanVariableName** to false and then you can toggle to change it to true

In your Parent.js add

```
@api booleanVariableName=false
```

**Here's an Example**

Parent.Js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
    @api booleanVariableName = false;

    handleClick() {
        this.booleanVariableName = !this.booleanVariableName;
    }
}
```

Parent.html

```
<template>
    <button onclick={handleClick}>Toggle Boolean</button>
    <c-bool show={booleanVariableName}></c-bool>
</template>
```

**but if your use case is that it should be true from the begining you can use this**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api booleanVariableName = false;

    connectedCallback() {
        // Set the boolean property to true dynamically
        this.booleanVariableName = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aman Patil, Thank you for your thorough explanation.
But I still wonder why we have to set default boolean value as a `false`. As we can toggle boolean value by `handleClick` function by HTML and JavaScript, It seems "Okay" to set default value as `true` as well. Is it just a specification of LWC?

Comment: Hi @mkzyk, as documentations says "Boolean attributes on standard HTML Elements are set to true by adding the attribute to the element. The absence of the attribute defaults the attribute to false. Therefore, the default value of an attribute is always false. Lightning web components use the same principle for boolean properties".

Answer (score 1):

This can be used as a work around.

`@api booleanVariableName = !false;`

Comment: Does this avoid the "unable to statically toggle the value to false in markup" issue mentioned in the documentation?